# Sails Js - Accessing multiple controller at the same time

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a problem with accessing multiple controller at the same time,
example I'm accessing the method "access" while "access" is active, I can't use/access the method "other" or other controllers in the client side,
but when the looping in "access" is done, I can use other methods or controllers, is SailsJs controller Single Threading?

```
access: function (req, res) {
  // Assume that I'll generate 1k data and I dont have problem about that
  // my problem is while generating 1k data i cant access my other Controller/Method
  // any solution about my problem thanks :) 
  // NOTE** this is just a example of the flow of my program
  // In creating data Im using Async

  while(x <= 1000) {
    Model.create(etc, function (err, ok) {
      if(err) console.log(err)
    });
    x++;
  }

  res.view('view/sampleview');
},

other: function (req, res) {
  res.view('view/view');
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All controllers and actions are avaible in sails.contollers variavel Mike sails.controllers.mycontroller.access (req, res);

run in parallel, all at same time:

```
access: function (req, res) {
  var createFunctions = [];  

  while(x <= 1000) {
    createFunctions.push(function(done) {
      Model.create(etc).exec(function (err, ok) {
        if(err) return done(err); // err
        done(); //success
      });
    })

    x++;
  }

  async.parallel( createFunctions, function afterAll(err) {
    sails.controllers.mycontroller.other (req, res);

    //res.view('view/sampleview');
  });
},

other: function (req, res) {
  res.view('view/view');
},
```

run in series, one by one:

```
access: function (req, res) {
  var createFunctions = [];  

  while(x <= 1000) {
    createFunctions.push(function(done) {
      Model.create(etc).exec(function (err, ok) {
        if(err) return done(err); // err
        done(); //success
      });
    })

    x++;
  }

  // run in series, one by one
  async.series( createFunctions, function afterAll(err) {
    sails.controllers.mycontroller.other (req, res);

    //res.view('view/sampleview');
  });
},

other: function (req, res) {
  res.view('view/view');
},
```

Comment: ahmm sir, what if i want to access the "other" in the client side?, I can't access the "other" while the "access" looping is not yet done. thats my problem, I'm wondering if the SailsJs is single thread controller, i think not

Comment: @PaulernestBautista ok, i changed my code to use async how are a global by default in sails.js

Comment: thats nice, now I have an idea what Im going to do in my project, thanks a lot!